# How to calculate p-value for significance test of variables in linear regression

Tags: regression, p-value, python, scikit-learn

I am trying to find the significance of predictors while using different linear regression models (**I am using Python scikit-learn**). Scikit-learn does not provide the pvalues of predictors( at least i did not find a way). So i would like to know how to calculate pvalues?
Puporpose is to find which all predictors are significant.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This question has been asked previously on stackoverflow. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928275/find-p-value-significance-in-scikit-learn-linearregression). Other than that [StatsModels](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/) is another fine Python package that provides the type of significance testing that you look for.